# HTML element not printing

Tags: css, html, printing

I'm generating a barcode using [this library](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator) and I do need to print the page including the barcode.

When I initiate the print dialog I can't find the barcode although it is taking up space.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .barcode-container {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subpage">
  <div class="barcode-container">
    <div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:422px;height:30px;">
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:16px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:28px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:36px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:56px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:74px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:82px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:94px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:110px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:116px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:124px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:132px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:138px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:146px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:154px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:160px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:168px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:176px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:182px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:190px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:198px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:204px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:212px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:220px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:226px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:234px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:242px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:248px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:256px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:264px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:272px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:280px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:286px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:292px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:300px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:308px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:314px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:324px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:330px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:336px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:344px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:352px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:358px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:368px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:374px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:382px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:390px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:396px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:406px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:414px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:418px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="bold">ID: 60105</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus luctus volutpat lorem a auctor. In lorem nisi, vulputate vel dapibus eu, tristique non lacus. Proin maximus nulla a imperdiet accumsan. Nullam diam tortor, hendrerit a libero vel, placerat
    ullamcorper urna. Vivamus consequat placerat lectus, mattis porttitor felis feugiat non. Quisque non elementum est. Quisque semper tincidunt nunc quis condimentum. Morbi tristique ipsum quis velit accumsan tincidunt. Etiam et imperdiet ex, at posuere
    enim. Curabitur vitae lacinia libero.</p>
</div>
```

I tried to do a `display: block !important;` to the barcode container but it still didn't print it. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have against stylesheets!? You could move `background-color:black;height:30px;top:0px;position:absolute;` into a common class and make that snippet a lot shorter and more readable.

Comment: @Blazemonger I have nothing against them. The library is generating those inline styles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Background colours don't print by default. They are set as transparent.

Try:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10000px #000; /*Fake Bg*/
```

---

Alternatively the user can set:

Tick '**Print Background Colours and Images**' from your browsers 'Page Setup'

---

You may also use:

```
-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
```

but this is only supported in **Chrome** *(And other Webkit browsers)*.

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm. I had to modify the library source files to inject a class because I can't for the life of me figure out the proper selector for the bars.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome css property "-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;" will make it work appropriately in chrome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .barcode-container>div{
    display: block !important;
   -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subpage">
  <div class="barcode-container">
    <div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:422px;height:30px;">
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:16px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:28px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:36px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:56px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:74px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:82px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:94px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:110px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:116px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:124px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:132px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:138px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:146px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:154px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:160px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:168px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:176px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:182px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:190px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:198px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:204px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:212px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:220px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:226px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:234px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:242px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:248px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:256px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:264px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:272px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:280px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:286px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:292px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:300px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:308px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:314px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:324px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:330px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:336px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:344px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:352px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:358px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:368px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:374px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:382px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:390px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:396px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:406px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:414px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:418px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="bold">ID: 60105</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus luctus volutpat lorem a auctor. In lorem nisi, vulputate vel dapibus eu, tristique non lacus. Proin maximus nulla a imperdiet accumsan. Nullam diam tortor, hendrerit a libero vel, placerat
    ullamcorper urna. Vivamus consequat placerat lectus, mattis porttitor felis feugiat non. Quisque non elementum est. Quisque semper tincidunt nunc quis condimentum. Morbi tristique ipsum quis velit accumsan tincidunt. Etiam et imperdiet ex, at posuere
    enim. Curabitur vitae lacinia libero.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` on **Chrome** and `color-adjust: exact;` on **Firefox**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
@media print {
  .barcode-container {
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    color-adjust: exact;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subpage">
  <div class="barcode-container">
    <div style="font-size:0;position:relative;width:422px;height:30px;">
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:6px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:16px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:22px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:28px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:36px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:44px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:56px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:66px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:74px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:82px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:88px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:94px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:100px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:110px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:116px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:124px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:132px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:138px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:146px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:154px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:160px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:168px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:176px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:182px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:190px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:198px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:204px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:212px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:220px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:226px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:234px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:242px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:248px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:256px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:264px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:272px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:280px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:286px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:292px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:300px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:308px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:314px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:324px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:330px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:336px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:344px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:352px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:358px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:368px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:374px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:382px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:390px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:396px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:6px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:406px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:2px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:414px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:4px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:418px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div style="background-color:black;width:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;left:422px;top:0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="bold">ID: 60105</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus luctus volutpat lorem a auctor. In lorem nisi, vulputate vel dapibus eu, tristique non lacus. Proin maximus nulla a imperdiet accumsan. Nullam diam tortor, hendrerit a libero vel, placerat
    ullamcorper urna. Vivamus consequat placerat lectus, mattis porttitor felis feugiat non. Quisque non elementum est. Quisque semper tincidunt nunc quis condimentum. Morbi tristique ipsum quis velit accumsan tincidunt. Etiam et imperdiet ex, at posuere
    enim. Curabitur vitae lacinia libero.</p>
</div>
```